# Error while converting csv to parquet file using pandas

Tags: pandas, parquet

I would like to upload csv as parquet file to S3 bucket. Below is the code snippet.

```
df = pd.read_csv('right_csv.csv')
csv_buffer = BytesIO()
df.to_parquet(csv_buffer, compression='gzip', engine='fastparquet')
csv_buffer.seek(0)
```

Above is giving me an error: `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not _io.BytesIO`
How to make it work?

Comment: If the answers solved your issue, kindly accept the one that was the most useful. If not do let know what the answers missed as a comment. More info on what to do when someone answers -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 3):

As per the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1.5/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_parquet.html), when `fastparquet` is used as the engine, `io.BytesIO` cannot be used. `auto` or `pyarrow` engine have to be used. Quoting from the documentation.

> The engine fastparquet does not accept file-like objects.

Below code works without any issues.

```
import io
f = io.BytesIO()
df.to_parquet(f, compression='gzip', engine='pyarrow')
f.seek(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answer, this is not supported. One work around would be to save as parquet to a [NamedTemporaryFile](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile). Then copy the content to a BytesIO buffer:

```py
import tempfile

with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile() as tmp:
    df.to_parquet(tmp.name, compression='gzip', engine='fastparquet')
    with open(tmp.name, 'rb') as fh:
        buf = io.BytesIO(fh.read())
```

Comment: @Simon It is the name of the temporary parquet file created. It is an attribute of the `tmp` object.